# How to get function attributes inside a html?

Tags: python, regex

edit:
yayy,this is the question that got me banned. thanks to the community.

I am trying to capture the function `redirecttoauth` with a regular expression, but it doesn't do what I expect.

```
start = 'function redirecttoauth(sessionid'
end = '}'
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
print(result)
```

and tried to escape `}` and `)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex is really the wrong way to do that. for a simple example your approach might work, you need the DOTALL flag though and you need to escape the parantheses:

```
import re
s = r'''<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function redirecttoauth(sessionid, test) {
   function body ...
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
'''

start = r'function redirecttoauth\(sessionid'
end = r'}'
result = re.search(r'%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s, re.DOTALL).group(1)
print(result)
```